# Apply multiple values to each row (R)

Tags: r

I have searched through multiple websites and although this problem is not that hard (I guess), I can't find the answer to it.

I have a data frame (that grows each month) with product codes and want to give them all a label with month and year:

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
```

Apply this `monthYear` (so all 48 "month-year" combination) to each row of this `data.frame`:

```
codes <- c("UIW786", "1UJ928", "JSNK928", "PEO9208", "NejU78")
codes2 <- c("34", "15", "166", "184", "3316")
codesDF <- data.frame(codes, codes2)
```

So I end up with 48*5 rows:

```
34  UIW786  2013-01-01  
34  UIW786  2013-01-02   
34  UIW786  2013-01-03  
....  
3316  NejU78  2016-11-01  
3316  NejU78  2016-12-01
```

I thought to repeat each value in `codesDF` 48 times and then `cbind` it, but when new codes come I need something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(codesDF) {...}
```

That's where I got stuck.

Hopefully someone could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does  `merge(monthYear,codesDF)` do the job?

Comment: sigh...I feel really stupid writing for loops Thank you very much.